# Vue CLI exclude js file from bundle

Tags: webpack, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

I have vue cli project. I want to exclude js files inside spesific folder using exclude rules, but not working.
Bundle file still have js code that i want to exclude.

I want exclude *.js files inside fake-db folder. Here is my folder structure

[image]

Using exclude rules inside configureWebpack but not working.

```js
  configureWebpack: () => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
      return {
        module: {
          rules: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/fake-db') 
          }]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

What the other way that I have to use for excluding spesific js file from bundling?

Comment: anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to exclude the test files from the bundle adding them to the `tsconfig.json` config file like this:

```
{

  "exclude": ["tests", "node_modules"]

}
```

The [typescript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) recommends using the `jsconfig.json` file for JS projects. Maybe this can work in your case, something like:

```
{
      "exclude": ["fake-db"]
}
```